# Solution to $\int x \sqrt[]{1-x^4}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Just finished my calculus exam and was stuck on trying to integrate this particular integral 
 $\int x \sqrt[]{1-x^4}dx$

I asked a few people after the exam and no one could solve it.
Is there something I'm overlooking here?

Answer (score 3):

*Hint1:* Variable change: $$y = x^2$$
$$ dy = 2xdx $$

*Hint2:* Integral $$\int\sqrt{1-y^2}dy$$

is known (that is, it should be in integral tables, like in this [link](http://www.integral-table.com/) or textbooks).

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Set $x^2=\sin\theta\implies0\le\theta\le\dfrac\pi2$

and $2x\ dx=?$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $t = x^2$, you should get

$$\frac{1}{2} \int \sqrt{1-t^2} \,dt$$

You can take it from here.